# Batching for a non-image data set with Tensorflow

Tags: python, random, tensorflow, batching

I am a beginner in tensorflow. 
I have a data set with 43 inputs and one output. I am gonna create a mini-batch of the data to run deep learning.

Here are my inputs:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 43])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None])
```

which I am feeding them from a matlab file, looking:

```
train_mat = train_mat["binary_train"].value
feed_dict={x:Train[0:100,0:43] , y_:Train[0:100,43]}
```

I am gonna have random batch instead of calling 0:100 records.
I saw

```
tf.train.batch
```

but, I could not realize how does it work. 
Could you please guide me how I can do that.

Thanks,
Afshin

Answer (score 0):

The `tf.train.batch` and other similar methods are based on Queues, which are best fit in parallel loading huge amount of samples asynchronously. The document [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/how_tos/threading_and_queues/index.html#threading-and-queues) describes basic of using queues in TensorFlow. There is also another blog describing [how to read data from files](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/how_tos/reading_data/index.html).

If you are going to use queues, the `placeholder` and `feed_dict` is unnecessary.

For your specific case, the potential solution maybe look like this:

```
from tensorflow.python.training import queue_runner

# capacity and min_after_dequeue could be set according to your case
q = tf.RandomShuffleQueue(1000, 500, tf.float32)
enq = q.enqueue_many(train_mat)
queue_runner.add_queue_runner(queue_runner.QueueRunner(q, [enq]))

deq = q.dequeue()
input = deq[:, 0:43]
label = deq[:, 43]

x, y_ = tf.train.batch([input, label], 100)

# then you can use x and y_ directly in inference and train process.
```

Code above is based on some hypothesis, because information provided in question is not sufficient. However, I hope the code could inspire you in some way.

Comment: It gives thw error: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'train'. One questions, why did you select 1000 and 500 in the RandomShuffleQueue?

Comment: Sorry for the typo. It should be `tf.nn.batch` instead of `tf.nn.train`.

Comment: Agian it says that AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'batch'.

Comment: My bad. It is `tf.train.batch`. Because the code is not complete, I did not try it in real environment. But I hope you could get some inspiration form the snippet.